# ms-dos batch file commands to implent c# code

Tags: c#

Here below I am pasting my commands what I used in ms-dos batch file and successfully run that batch file also and got admin privilege for the user.

```
 set "params=%*"
```

**(Below total command in single line only)**

```
 cd /d "%~dp0" && ( if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del
 "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul
 2>nul || (  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) :
 UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %params%", "",
 "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && exit
 /B )
```

**(Above total command in single line only)**

```
 net start MSSQL$SQL2016
```

I tried Below code in c#

```
Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/all";
            process.Start();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("set "+"params=% *"+"");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("cd /d "+" % ~dp0"+" && ( if exist " +" % temp % \" getadmin.vbs"+" del "+" % temp %\"getadmin.vbs"+" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul 2>nul || (  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("+"Shell.Application"+"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "+"cmd.exe"+", "+" / k cd "+" % ~sdp0"+" && % ~s0 %params% "+", "+","+"runas"+", 1 >> "+" % temp %"+"\"+"+"getadmin.vbs"+" && "+" % temp %\"getadmin.vbs"+" && exit /B )");
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("net start MSSQL$SQL2016");
            process.StandardInput.Flush();
            process.StandardInput.Close();
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            Console.Read();
```

when I ran this file in c# no result and showing no error also. So I did some mistakes. So maybe you people can help me to get rid of this.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You don't need a batch file to start other processes. You don't need `cmd.exe` either, unless you really need to execute a batch file. If you want to start the SQL Server service you can use the correct .NET classes directly. On the other hand, SQL Server is a *server*, it's meant to always be up

Comment: @ Panagiotis I wrote this to execute my client's side when they run my application. Sometimes they are getting some error SQL server not found. That time manually we have to run that server in services

Comment: You can control any service with the [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) class. You can also use [the SMO classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/managing-services-and-network-settings-by-using-wmi-provider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) to start/stop the server, create databases, backups, etc

Comment: that's not DOS, don't call it like that. [DOS and Windows cmd are completely different things](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386). The above script won't ever run in DOS

Comment: @vijay, why are you doing ugly things like `"set "+"params=% *"+""` instead of `"set params=% *"`? Also, you don't need a cmd script for this, but even if you do, why not have a batch file and run it?

Comment: @Andrew see above dos command set "params=%*".  And this one I am running client side. so when the SQL server error came, I can't run client-side and can't tell him to run that batch file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to execute PowerShell commands -- CreateObject, UAC.ShellExecute -- with cmd.exe. The process.StartInfo.FileName field should probably be set to powershell.exe or pwsh.exe.

Comment: @ padeso If I replace cmd.exe with powershell.exe and ran the project but no result. I replaced it with pwsh.exe and ran the project, I got an error that "The system cannot find the file specified"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the *real* question is how to start/stop the SQL Server service. One way to do this is using the [ServiceController](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) class.

```
var name="MSSQL$SQL2016";
var service=ServiceController.GetServices()
                             .First(svc=>svc.ServiceName==name);
service.Start();
```

Another way is to use the [SQL Server Management Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/tasks/managing-services-and-network-settings-by-using-wmi-provider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16). These classes can be used to start/stop services, create databases, backups etc.

```
var mc = new ManagedComputer();
svc = mc.Services("MSSQL$SQL2016");
svc.Start();
```

Comment: @ panagiotis var service=ServiceController.GetServices()                    
                                                                      .First(svc=>svc.ServiceName==name); I added. But it is showing an error that ServiceController[] does not contain a definition for first.